# You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list error

Tags: apt, python

I'm trying to install python imaging library because it's a dependency for some other stuff.

but when I try to do it I get this

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging       
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Comment: If you want to install `python-imaging`, why not just install `python-imaging` (rather than installing its build dependencies?)

Comment: @steeldriver i used a command on this site to do that now i did `sudo apt-get install python-imaging` and everything is alright, thanks alot